# Prepare extras for next Activity launch

Tags: android, android-activity, extras

I want to set some Extras for the next startup of an activity. However, I want the user to start the activity, i don't want to start it programatically with startActivity();

It should also work if the target activity is currently killed.

Could you tell me how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: "I want the user to start the activity, i don't want to start it programatically with startActivity();" huh?

Comment: I want that these Extras are loaded automatically when the app is started by the user the next time :-)

Comment: Then you will need to store them in some type of [Persistent Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and store variables to non-volatile memory. Then read them in the onCreate() of your activity.

Comment: Yes, i knew about this option before. However, I would prefer using intents or PendingIntents it seems cleaner to me. Is it possible to use this mechanism?